# UploadFile control - get data

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

How to get data (read file) chosen in FileUpload control without [`FileUpload.SaveAs Method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.saveas.aspx) on the server? Is it possible write it at once to some object?

Comment: you can access to the stream of the file with PostedFile and you can load it in a memory stream or into a byte array without saving it on the web server, sey ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `FileUpload.FileContent` gives you a `Stream` to work with.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.filecontent.aspx).

For example:

```
void WriteFileLength()
{
    if (fileUpload.HasFile)
    {
        var fileStream = fileUpload.FileContent;
        var messageFormat = "The file is {0} bytes in length"
        Response.Write(string.Format(messageFormat, fileStream.Length));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have access to the byte[] of the upload by using

```
FileUpload1.FileBytes
```

where FileUpload1 is the control.